Rendering Quarto document doesn't find .R files in package
When I'm creating a simple R package I would like to use the functions created in .R files in my test_doc.qmd file. The problem is that when rendering the qmd file the function not is found while it is created in the package. It works when I use devtools::load_all() so then I the function is found in the code chunk without running it manually in the console. I tried to create a reproducible example on this GitHub repo: https://github.com/QuintenSand/test_package
So you should first clone the repo and then try to run the qmd file:
---
title: "Test quarto doc"
format: html
editor: visual
---

## Quarto

Test if the function will be rendered:

```{r}
test_function(TRUE)
```

The function test_function is in the test_function.R file. It returns the following error when rendering the document:
processing file: test_doc.qmd
  |...................................                 |  67% [unnamed-chunk-1]


Quitting from lines 12-13 [unnamed-chunk-1] (test_doc.qmd)
Error in `test_function()`:
! could not find function "test_function"
                                                                                                            
Execution halted

But when I run devtools::load_all():
devtools::load_all()
ℹ Loading test

And the code chunk:

You can see it works even when the function is not in the global environment. So I was wondering how we can render the quarto documents when having .R custom functions in the document?

If you actually need a package then you should

build the package and
load the package using library() in your Quarto source.

Assuming that the package will be called test (based on your DESCRIPTION file):
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: visual
---

```{r}
library(test)
```

Test if the function will be rendered:

```{r}
test_function(TRUE)
```

Alternatively, if you only want to use a function from a specific file then you could just source the content of that file into your Quarto source.
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: visual
---

```{r}
source("test_function.R")
```

Test if the function will be rendered:

```{r}
test_function(TRUE)
```

If the .R file is in a sub-directory (like in your example repository) then you'll need to include that in the path like source("R/test_function.R").
